# How to write first non-missing value to first missing observations

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset

```
id  rate
 1     .
 2     .
 3  0.01
 4  0.02
 5     .
 6     .
```

How can I efficiently write the first non-missing rate to the observations before it and the last non-missing rate to the observations after it? So that:

```
id  rate
 1  0.01
 2  0.01
 3  0.01
 4  0.02
 5  0.02
 6  0.02
```

I can fill the final values (see code below), but I have not got a clue on how to do the first ones - without resorting to auxiliary tables, which in my case may (or not) make this very inefficient, as I will have millions of records.

```
data have;
    input id rate;
    datalines;
     1     .
     2     .
     3  0.01
     4  0.02
     5     .
     6     .
run;

data want(drop=previous);
    set have;
    retain previous;
    if not nmiss(rate) then previous = rate;
    else rate = previous;
run;
```

Comment: Is this data set properly representative of your problem?

Comment: Well, there are far more observations than this, so the issue will be more variables and by groups. I would say 1000 records per each by group, and 1 million by groups. So, 1 billion records.

Comment: Well, a simple solution is to sort in descending order afterwards and applying the same procedure. Is there any better way?

Comment: For each group, you're going to have at most one case of filling in the 'before's and then you'll have some number of 'after's?  Or is that also only one 'after'?  Some of the 'most efficient' depends on the specifics of your data.

Comment: I did not fully understand your question. It is always as in the example above - missing observations, then non-missing observations, then missing observations, no exceptions. They do vary in number though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the most efficient answer is. You may just want to fill in the final values with the method you have, then reverse sort the data set and fill in the rest of the values using the same method. However here is an alternative method I came up with, I'm not sure how efficient it is but you could try it:

```
data have;
input id group rate;
datalines;
 1  1    .
 2  1    .
 3  1 0.01
 4  1 0.02
 5  1    .
 6  1    .
 7  2    .
 8  2    .
 9  2    .
10  2 0.03
11  2 0.07
12  2    .
;

data want(drop=next initial);
    retain next;
    do until (rate ne . or last.group);
        set have;
        by group id;
    end;
    if rate ne . then next = rate;
    do until (initial ne . or last.group);
        set have;
        by group id;
        initial = rate;
        if initial = . then rate = next;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

I added a group variable since you said you would be working with by groups. The program cycles through the data twice, once to get the first non-missing rate, next to apply that rate to the missings and output to the final data set. "next" is the value missing rates are replaced with, and "initial" is the initial rate for each observation.

For each group the processing goes like this: The first "do until" loop reads through the data set "have" until it finds a non-missing rate. The variable "next" is set to equal that rate. The second "do until" loop reads through "have", setting "rate" equal to "next", until it finds the first non-missing rate. Then both loops read through the non-missing rates and the second loop outputs them. The last non-missing rate is saved to "next". Then the loops cycle through the missing rates at the end, replacing them with the value from "next" and outputting them.

Comment: I have implemented your code and it works exactly as I need. Thank you very much. As for efficiency, I am yet to test the remaining options, but yours processes 880501622 observations and 8 variable in 6:36.22 / 4:40.40 (real vs cpu time), which is very good for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

The DoW solution is a good one, but there is a slightly faster option, particularly related to CPU time.  This also results in a slightly different result as far as which record fills in blanks, which is not entirely clear from the question which is better.

In the DoW solution, you have to iterate through every single record twice, while you can use POINT to just iterate through the needed few records until you get to the first record with data per group and then move on.

Also, this solution will fill in later records with the *prior* nonmissing record, while the DoW solution as presented fills them with the *next* nonmissing record, unless the last record is missing.

The POINT solution is much faster for 10000 groups/1000 IDs; I suspect that is because that size of dataset is within my machine's disk caching size (CPU time = Real time).  Add a zero, 1e5 groups, and it's no longer much faster in real time; it's about the same as the DoW solution in real time (8 or 10 more seconds out of 2 minutes), but the CPU time is about half as long (Point=35 seconds, DoW=1:09).

Both this and the DoW loop require the data to be sorted by group, or at least arranged by group (groups don't have to be in order proper, you could use `notsorted` to prevent that from throwing an error, but the data *inside* any given group needs to be consecutive).  This doesn't require sorting by ID, and neither does (as far as I can tell) the DoW loop.

```
%let numgroups=1e5;
%let numingroup=1000;
data have;
do group = 1 to &numgroups.;
  do id = 1 to &numingroup.;
    if id > 5 then do;
        rate = rand('Normal',1,1);
        if rate < 0 then call missing(rate);
    end;
    output;
  end;
end;
run;


data want_Point;
 set have;
 by group;
 if (first.group) and (missing(rate)) then do; *if missing first row, enter this loop;
    do __point = _n_+1 by 1;
      set have(keep=group rate rename=(group=_group rate=new_rate)) point=__point;  *iterate through dataset from current row;
      if (not missing (new_rate) or group ne _group) then leave; *grab nonmissing row, leave loop - and have safety to leave loop if entire group is missing;
    end;
 end;
 else do;
   new_rate = coalesce(rate,new_rate);  *grab updated rate, if needed. new_rate is automatically retained since it comes in on set statement;
 end;
 rename new_rate=rate;  *move it over to rate;
 drop rate;  *drop old rate variable;
 output;
 if last.group then call missing(new_rate); *make extra sure we are safe;
run;



data want_DoW(drop=next initial);
    retain next;
    do until (rate ne . or last.group);
        set have;
        by group id;
    end;
    if rate ne . then next = rate;
    do until (initial ne . or last.group);
        set have;
        by group id;
        initial = rate;
        if initial = . then rate = next;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you @Joe. I have already implemented the solution above, but I will try yours and get back at you.